# TFS 2010 vs TFS 2012 event handling

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010, tfs-2012

I was wondering if someone can tell me if there is any changes in how events are sent and received in tfs 2012. I searched the website and it looks like it's pretty much the same except another UI is added in 2012. Is there any other interior changes? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly the same, new UI, that's the right description. Even on the server side things have remained mostly the same, but some types have moved from one assembly to the other, so there are some implementation changes that are otherwise invisible to a normal user.

Comment: So is it safe to assume that the way i'm handling tfs events right now(i have a wcf service listen to events -> send to tibco queue to log) will need no changes should we switch to tfs 2012? I'm asking especially in terms of the code needed to complete this. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: That still works, though the SOAP webservice is "the old way". In 2010 the ISubscriber interface was introduced to allow you to execute these things in process http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.framework.server.isubscriber.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you happen to have an example of isubscriber in action? All i found was this: http://exsertus.files.wordpress.com/2013/09/blog-1.png.

Comment: And most importantly, does Isubscriber method work in tfs 2012?

Comment: Isubscriber works on TFS 2010 all the way up to 2013. The TFS Aggregator project dives deeply into it: http://tfsaggregator.codeplex.com